# I get a "permission denied" when I try to access my ssd's

Tags: permissions

I am the single owner and user of my computer. I am restricted from accessing two of my SSDs.
How do i change it? I don't know what to look at so I can't show you anything.

I installed the latest Leap 42.2 with 3 SSDs. The os is on my M.2 and I have 2 Samsung SSDs for storage. If I try to use the SSDs I get a "permission denied".

Comment: Did you partition and format the devices and added mount points? Please also share with us how you try to access the SSDs exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the permissions if it says "you are not the owner so you cannot change the permissions" then you need boot it with live media and change permissions for each of them.